# Example WriteBack with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm just starting to use nodejs. I've done some basic learning course but I miss any basic example to start becaue I'm having problems to deploy an scenario for the first time.
The scenario I need to cover is:
I just need to write and read data from an Access.MDB file.
I have a basic example that works if I execute the js with the sentence \node appnodemdb.js from the command line.

But I need to execute it from another js in a web.

So I'd appreciate a lot if anyone could send me an example about execute it from an other js without the command line.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you explain what do you mean by "to execute it from another js in a web"?

Comment: Hi, I'll try to explain it better:

Comment: Hi Pavlo, I'm building an extension for a BI tool based in HTML5. The extension must be build with JavaScript but finally it's visualized in a HTML5 environment. So I'm not sure how should I prepare the environment and how to call the nodejs 'requires' to make it run in the browser without the commandline. Thks again

Answer (score 1):

You can't call directly some NodeJS code with the browser. To achieve what you want, the simplest way to do is:

1. Create an HTTP server with a URL to will launch your write/write action and return some value (with [Express](http://expressjs.com/) for example).
2. This URL will be called by your JS in the browser (using XHR/Ajax) and process the data returned.

They are tons of alternative to do this, but since you tell us that you are beginner, I suggest this approach.